# How to delete parts of local storage with removeItem?

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I am creating a web app which tracks people's weight. I have one page where an array is stored in local storage and displayed to the user.

The page im currently working on now, inputs the users target weight and displays it to them.

I originally had this working with a localStorage.clear() however i noticed that this also wiped my array on the other page. I am trying to use the localStorage.RemoveItem, however it just seems to remove the input button and not the data.

Can anybody help me with this?

This is my script.

*UPDATE********

```
function storeText(inputID) {

//Clears old target weight
//localStorage.clear(); 

//check to see if the localStorage item already exists
var userInput = localStorage.userInfo;

//set it up for new data to be appended
if(userInput!=null) userInput+=" ";
else userInput="";

//add the new data
userInput += document.getElementById(inputID).value;

//set the localStorage field with the updated data
localStorage.userInfo = userInput;




}

 function UpdateWeight(inputID){

    localStorage.userInfo = document.getElementById(inputID).value;

    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = localStorage.userInfo;

}


</script>
```

input

```
<input size="10" id="userText" type="text"/>            
        <input type="button" class="greyButton" value="submit" onclick= "UpdateWeight(inputID)"/>
        <div id="result">           
        Result here
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

rename the function

```
remove();
```

to

```
removeStorage();
```

remember to update the onClick as well.

```
remove();
```

is running on the button not calling your function!

A much more sucinct function would be:

```
function UpdateWeight(inputID){

    localStorage.userInfo = document.getElementById(inputID).value;

    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = localStorage.userInfo;

}
```

From what you have shown this does what you want - replaces original item with new item on button click?

Comment: sorry i did not see the bottom half of your comment i will try your functon.

Comment: by the wak - onclick should ONLY contain that one function UpdateWeight - the others are not necessary with this.

Comment: so the UdateWeight function is the only one i need? its still not playing ball

Comment: UpdateWeight(inputID) needs to be UpdateWeight("userText") - you have to pass in the ID of what you want.

Comment: I got it to work by adding localStorage.userInfo = document.getElementById(inputID).value; to the bottom of my original store Text function.Cheers!!

Comment: great - if you want to mark my answer as correct and give me a +1 it would be appreciated - best of luck with it all!

Comment: it says i have to have 15+ reputation to do so, im a noob on this site im afraid. thank you for being patient.

Comment: no probs - I was a noob here yesterday :-P built 400 rep in 2 days :-D